# Como mudar a cor da seleção de texto no VS Code?

Tags: html, css, json, visual-studio-code

Na imagem, o texto selecionado está com a cor preta, eu quero colocar uma cor mais clara.

[image: print do visual studio code]

Comment: Mude o tema para um que te agrade. Acho que não tem como mudar só uma cor, talvez com alguma extensão

Comment: @Costamilam jovem tem como mudar sim, está na própria especificação do VS Code, depois se te interessar da uma olhada nessa lista. https://code.visualstudio.com/api/references/theme-color#editor-colors Normalmente tudo que começa com `editor.` é referente a área onde digitamos o código.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Vc pode customizar isso entrando nos seus `Setting` e colocando isso

```
"editor.selectionBackground": "#666",
"editor.selectionHighlightBackground": "#666",
```

`#666` é a cor, vc pode testar uma cor mais clara que te agrade...

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

**Vc entra nas Configs aqui**

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]